# Lambda Chaining Design Pattern

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

Currently working on a project for school where I've run into the issue of having to chain network calls. An example of this would be something like this.

I want to get an object of type C from the server, however, to get C I need an object B, but I only have access to an object of type A so I need to make a request chain.

Currently the chain looks like this.

```
class View {
      .......
      makeServerRequest(A, resultBCallback)
    }

    private void resultBCallback(B result) {
        makeServerRequest(B, resultCCallback)
    }

    private void resultCCallback(C result) {
       ...use C to update UI
    }
}
```

So far I've just abstracted this out from the view and into a specific class that handles the chaining and set it up as an observable so the view only knows that it needs a type C object and has an A object and passes that to the class. I'm wondering if there is a specific design pattern to handle this kind of issue, or something that could make it more generic/easy to work with.

I understand that something like rxJava would fix this issues, but because of group constraints it's not feasible to use that.

Comment: I don't think there's a better solution other than using rxjava. Otherwise, this is the only solution for it, and be careful of the "callback hell".

Comment: Why you need a design pattern here? I don't think that there exists any design pattern with the above intent. Using RxJava and it's operators would solve the problem however.

Comment: Just trying to find something that might help clean up the code a bit, and hopefully help remove some of the code duplication.